# Characterization of planar domains onto which a unit disk can be mapped with constant singular values

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isoperimetric-problems

It can be shown that there are (smoothly bounded, Jordan) domains $E\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ which are $\textit{not}$ images of mappings $f$ from the unit disk (or any other planar domain), such that $\mathrm{d}f$ has fixed, constant singular values. That is, such mappings have 'limited transformation capability'.

On the other hand, I wonder if a characterization of all those domains onto which the unit disk (or more generally, any planar domain) can be transformed to by such $f$'s.

Comment: Could you please give an example of a domain mentioned in the first sentence or give a proof/reference? Does "smoothly bounded" mean that the boundary is a $\mathbb C^\infty$ curve? Note that if $E$ is any domain in $\mathbb R^2$ then for any linear map $L$ we have $E=L(L^{-1} E)$, this seem to contradict to your first sentence...

Comment: @DmitriPanov Yes, the result I'm citing is from this* work: "For each smoothly bounded Jordan domain $D$, there exists a
constant $C = C_D$ such that $\lambda_1(\partial E) \leq  C \lambda_2 (E)/\iota(E)$ for every Jordan domain $E$ which the image of $D$ under a cps-homeomorphism" (In our language a cps-homeom. is a mapping with constant singular values. And $\iota(E)$ is the inradios, i.e., the radius of the greatest inscribed circle. $\lambda_1$ the length and $\lambda_2$ the area). Not every $E$ satisfies such inequality given $D$. *https://doi.org/10.1155/S0161171203204166 (theorem 3.1)

Comment: @DmitriPanov What the previous inequality shows is that, for any constant singular values $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, there are domains $E$ that cannot be obtained from an arbitrary $D$ (in particular, the unit disk). And in principle yes, I am restricted to $\mathbb{C}^\infty$ curves. Thank you !